# Coffee still left in filter part

Tags: equipment

I am using Philips HD 7450/20 6 Cups Coffee Maker . Recently After every cycle I find that some coffee(brewed) is still left in the filter part. I tried cleaning the equipment using vinegar.

Can someone suggest how to resolve this.

Comment: Welcome to Coffee SE! Do you mean that not all coffee drips down into the jug?

Comment: yes.some amount is always left behind in the filter

Comment: I suspect your filter is getting clogged with coffee grounds that are too-finely ground. What kind of filter are you using (paper, metal, nylon, ...)? How do you grind your coffee? Does it *ever* drip out (like after an hour of letting it drain)?

Comment: paper filter.I was using finely grinded coffee.It does not drip out

Comment: Can you add a picture of said machine?

Comment: @coffee : http://img6a.flixcart.com/image/coffee-maker/g/9/f/philips-hd7450-hd-7450-400x400-imadbgg73hcavgem.jpeg

Comment: Most coffee machines have a mechanism on the filter basket to stop the flow of coffee when you pull the carafe out(the glass jug). The carafe should have a plastic lid which should depress the release on the filter basket. If that plastic lid is not in place the filter basket will not expel coffee. Make sure that the lid is in place, and its depressing the valve on the filter basket. Also make sure nothing is making this valve stick, and that coffee isn't clogging this valve.

Answer (score 2):

From what your question seems to be asking - I believe that grinding your coffee more coarse is all that needs to be done. Water will drain quicker through more coarsely ground coffee, and it seems like all the fine particles are eventually clogging the bottom of the cone.

Comment: I think it's as simple as this -- using a coarseness-of-grind that is compatible with the method (filter/drip!). @shrey - Did this fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you're cleaning the equipment at least 15 minutes after finishing your coffee (and you threw away the leftover paper filter), then I can't see where else the coffee would come from. Though sometimes I think some of the coffee will evaporate up , and fall back down as precipitation. But in that case it's water.

If this doesn't help , then ... without more information, I'm thinking your machine may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the machine with hot water and baking soda.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to provide some more specific information about why this might help solve this particular problem? We appreciate considered, thorough, on-point answers most!